# Robotframework: How to evaluate boolean value returned from Javascript call

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I was quite puzzled that this failed with a `NameError`:

```
${val} =    Execute Javascript    return sessionStorage.isMatching    
Should Be True     ${val}
```

Log output was:

```
INFO Executing JavaScript:
INFO ${val} = true 
KEYWORD  BuiltIn . Should Be True ${val} 
TRACE Arguments: [ 'true' ] 
FAIL Evaluating expression 'true' failed: NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

This doesn't work neither:

```
Should Be True     ${val} == true    -->  Evaluating expression 'true == true' failed: NameError: name 'true' is not defined
Should Be True     ${val} == 'true'  -->  Evaluating expression 'true == 'true'' failed: NameError: name 'true' is not defined
Should Be True     ${val} == "true"  -->  Evaluating expression 'true == "true"' failed: NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

After reading the docs I learned that underlying python doesn't evaluate JS `true` as `true`. I then tried to convert the boolean to String in JS:

```
${val} =    Execute Javascript    return sessionStorage.isMatching.toString()
```

but I got a `NameError`, again.

The only way I know is this which looks awful (because I explicitly have to convert a boolean value to boolean):

```
${val} =    Execute Javascript    return sessionStorage.isMatching
${bool} =    Convert To Boolean    ${val}
Should Be True     ${bool}
```

Is there a better way, to evaluate this in either RF or JS?

Versions:

> Python    2.7.8
>
> Robotframework    3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you get back from javascript is the literal string `'true'`. To use it in an expression you must quote it:

```
Should be true    '${val}` == 'true'
```

The reason you get the error `NameError: name 'true' is not defined` is due to the fact that robot does string substitution before evaluating the expression.

In other words, this expression in robot:

```
should be true ${val} == 'true'
```

... is the same as if you had typed this in python:

```
if true == 'true': 
    ...
```

Python sees `true`, tries to look up the value of a variable named `true`, and doens't find any such variable. Thus, you get the `NameError`.

You can find a description of this in the documentation for the [BuiltIn library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) (emphasis mine):

> When a variable is used in the expressing using the normal ${variable} syntax, its value is replaces before the expression is evaluated. This means that **the value used in the expression will be the string representation of the variable value, not the variable value itself**. This is not a problem with numbers and other objects that have a string representation that can be evaluated directly, but with other objects the behavior depends on the string representation. Most importantly, strings must always be quoted, and if they can contain newlines, they must be triple quoted.

Comment: _robot does string substitution before evaluating the expression_  which is a very nice feature. And I've got a lot of lines like `Run Keyword If  '${exp}' == 'None'`. So I should've known  - just didn't come to mind, this time. Thanks.